# Jquery Solution for Equal Height on Varied Class in CMS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

sorry to ask but looked everywhere for an "equal height" content solution. So far all options using Jquery (or script) rely on there being the same "class" assigned to target. For example, as in the below which demonstrates using '.someclass':

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
     var biggestHeight = 0;  
    $('.someclass').each(function(){  
    if($(this).height() > biggestHeight){  
        biggestHeight = $(this).height();  
      }  
    });  
    $('.someclass').height(biggestHeight);  
});
```

The problem is I'm working in a platform environment (square space) where there's numerous classes and no single .class over-arching that can be applied to the various module (block) type elements that can be added. In that environment, text blocks (.sqs-block-content) differs from image blocks (.sqs-block-image) and ongoing....

I'm not able to write my own "classes" then just apply some script and need help finding the classes to select and a script to make text modules equal image modules. And not script savvy enough to write it. Can anyone assist?

Basically looking to target a text block  on the page and fix it to the height of an image block next to it so that these are the SAME height.

Here's an actual page view showing text next to images which you can run inspection on and see what I mean. It's a trial/demo example so you may see a captcha first... > https://goo.gl/WksRqG

I'd be willing to pay for the help -- just can't seem to get this.... All solutions ultimately require either the same class assigned, or, the ability to wrap them in a custom div which I can't actually specify in the environment.

Thanks in advance for any help/walk through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have errors in the console. Looks like Jquery does not load because your site is HTTPS which is secure and you are loading Jquery from a HTTP site

[image]

Check here for a CDN Link for Jquery that loads it from a HTTPS hosting site

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/

Now that Jquery is fixed, all you need to do is this

**Code** Copy and paste in the browsers console to see the result. The footer will change size so i suggest a unique class for it not `.sqs-block-content`

```
var imheight = $(".sqs-block-image").height()
$(".sqs-block-content").css("height", imheight+"px")
```

**Result**

[image]

For window resize just add a function to recalculate

**Code**

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    var newheight = $(".sqs-block-image").height()
    $(".sqs-block-content").css("height", newheight +"px")
};
```

Comment: Hey Tasos -- thx much. Unfortunately I'm still stuck on this. It's been a problem all around with or without https.... I believe it's because unlike writing your own classes, it's pendant on the pre-written module formats in platform evirons. Doesn't seem to matter what class is called...

Comment: @Cjans give me second, now that Jquery is working ill try and fix the issue with the box heights

Comment: Yes Tasos, thanks much. Seriously -- I will pay for your time this is driving me crazy -- I removed the scripts prior so there's nothing on the page now (https://goo.gl/WksRqG) . If I delay in reply apologies in advance.

Comment: really thank you *much*. Was so stuck on this... Can I offer anything for the time? This worked pretty well (except the blocks don't say sized on browser re-size) --- sorry to post comments here -- can I message you?

Comment: @Cjans check update in answer for window resize -- Dont worry about a reward, just vote and accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like you know the class of the row elements, so select the immediate children of the rows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var biggestHeight = 0;  
    $('.sqs-row').children().each(function(){  
        if($(this).height() > biggestHeight){  
            biggestHeight = $(this).height();  
        }  
    });  
    $('.sqs-row').children().height(biggestHeight);  
});
```

If you want to do it on a per-row basis:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.sqs-row').each(function(){   
        var biggestHeight = 0;  
        $(this).children().each(function(){  
            if($(this).height() > biggestHeight){  
                biggestHeight = $(this).height();  
            }
        });
        $(this).children().height(biggestHeight);
    });  
});
```

Comment: Jeff B: thanks much for the speedy reply -- I'm working on that (did try .row and .sqs-row prior) -- still not working for me.... Will update... REALLY appreciate the help.

Comment: Unfortunately, using .sqs-rows also does not work... I would edit my comment prior but there's not an option for me to yet...I removed all the script on the example here: https://goo.gl/WksRqG if there's any other suggestions ... I'd welcome them. Thanks a bunch to you all.